# Figure environment not working with included file (extra } or forgotten endgroup)

Tags: floats, color, programming, include

I've spent hours on this issue. I hope someone can help me. I'm running into some kind of interference when I try to use the figure environment (Likewise for table, might be related to floats). I finally narrowed the problem down to one line-- where I include another file in the preamble that allows me to later include python code and have Latex color code it. The code I'm trying to compile is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\include{pythonperfect}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 blah blah blah
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where "pythonperfect" is:

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[procnames]{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{palatino}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Code Listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code Listing}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0,0.7,0}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.5}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
%\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]{
\lstset{
language=python,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\setstretch{1},
stringstyle=\color{green},
showstringspaces=false,
alsoletter={1234567890},
otherkeywords={\ , \}, \{},
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
emph={access,and,as,break,class,continue,def,del,elif,else,%
except,exec,finally,for,from,global,if,import,in,is,%
lambda,not,or,pass,print,raise,return,try,while,assert},
emphstyle=\color{orange}\bfseries,
emph={[2]self},
emphstyle=[2]\color{gray},
emph={[4]ArithmeticError,AssertionError,AttributeError,BaseException,%
DeprecationWarning,EOFError,Ellipsis,EnvironmentError,Exception,%
False,FloatingPointError,FutureWarning,GeneratorExit,IOError,%
ImportError,ImportWarning,IndentationError,IndexError,KeyError,%
KeyboardInterrupt,LookupError,MemoryError,NameError,None,%
NotImplemented,NotImplementedError,OSError,OverflowError,%
PendingDeprecationWarning,ReferenceError,RuntimeError,RuntimeWarning,%
StandardError,StopIteration,SyntaxError,SyntaxWarning,SystemError,%
SystemExit,TabError,True,TypeError,UnboundLocalError,UnicodeDecodeError,%
UnicodeEncodeError,UnicodeError,UnicodeTranslateError,UnicodeWarning,%
UserWarning,ValueError,Warning,ZeroDivisionError,abs,all,any,apply,%
basestring,bool,buffer,callable,chr,classmethod,cmp,coerce,compile,%
complex,copyright,credits,delattr,dict,dir,divmod,enumerate,eval,%
execfile,exit,file,filter,float,frozenset,getattr,globals,hasattr,%
hash,help,hex,id,input,int,intern,isinstance,issubclass,iter,len,%
license,list,locals,long,map,max,min,object,oct,open,ord,pow,property,%
quit,range,raw_input,reduce,reload,repr,reversed,round,set,setattr,%
slice,sorted,staticmethod,str,sum,super,tuple,type,unichr,unicode,%
vars,xrange,zip},
emphstyle=[4]\color{purple}\bfseries,
upquote=true,
morecomment=[s][\color{lightgreen}]{"""}{"""},
commentstyle=\color{red}\slshape,
literate={>>>}{\textbf{\textcolor{darkred}{>{>}>}}}3%
         {...}{{\textcolor{gray}{...}}}3,
procnamekeys={def,class},
procnamestyle=\color{blue}\textbf,
%framexleftmargin=1mm, framextopmargin=1mm, frame=shadowbox,
%rulesepcolor=\color{blue},
breaklines=true,
}{}
```

The error I get is:

```
! Too many }'s.
\color@endbox->\color@endgroup \egroup
l.10 \end{figure}
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.
```

In any case, I've used "pythonperfect" for a while, and never ran into an issue until today when I tried to include a figure. The problem is that I don't really understand most of what's happening in that file, I found it somewhere on the web (I don't remember where) and made a few changes to make it work for me. But I don't really understand it. So I can't figure out what's wrong.

I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

Comment: The minimal example compiles for me without errors with a freshly updated TeXLive installation. What versions of the used packages are you using? You can display that in the `.log` file using `\listfiles` in the preamble.

Comment: I encountered a problem with seemingly identical symptoms and solved it by updating setspace.sty from a 1990 version to version 6.7a (dated Dec. 2000). Then run sudo texhash in that directory.

Answer (score 6):

As Martin Scharrer mentioned in his comment, the example works. However, I think the problem starts in the moment you use the newly defined environment
`\lstnewenvironment`.

There was a closing `}` missing and when you used

```
\begin{python}

\end{python}
```

the error message came up. Have a look at this file's very last line. I also un-commented the new environment definition.

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[procnames]{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{palatino}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Code Listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code Listing}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0,0.7,0}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.5}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]{%%%% Included this
\lstset{
language=python,
 basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\setstretch{1},
 stringstyle=\color{green},
 showstringspaces=false,
 alsoletter={1234567890},
 otherkeywords={\ , \}, \{},
 keywordstyle=\color{blue},
 emph={access,and,as,break,class,continue,def,del,elif,else,%
 except,exec,finally,for,from,global,if,import,in,is,%
 lambda,not,or,pass,print,raise,return,try,while,assert},
 emphstyle=\color{orange}\bfseries,
 emph={[2]self},
 emphstyle=[2]\color{gray},
 emph={[4]ArithmeticError,AssertionError,AttributeError,BaseException,%
DeprecationWarning,EOFError,Ellipsis,EnvironmentError,Exception,%
False,FloatingPointError,FutureWarning,GeneratorExit,IOError,%
ImportError,ImportWarning,IndentationError,IndexError,KeyError,%
KeyboardInterrupt,LookupError,MemoryError,NameError,None,%
NotImplemented,NotImplementedError,OSError,OverflowError,%
PendingDeprecationWarning,ReferenceError,RuntimeError,RuntimeWarning,%
StandardError,StopIteration,SyntaxError,SyntaxWarning,SystemError,%
SystemExit,TabError,True,TypeError,UnboundLocalError,UnicodeDecodeError,%
UnicodeEncodeError,UnicodeError,UnicodeTranslateError,UnicodeWarning,%
UserWarning,ValueError,Warning,ZeroDivisionError,abs,all,any,apply,%
basestring,bool,buffer,callable,chr,classmethod,cmp,coerce,compile,%
complex,copyright,credits,delattr,dict,dir,divmod,enumerate,eval,%
execfile,exit,file,filter,float,frozenset,getattr,globals,hasattr,%
hash,help,hex,id,input,int,intern,isinstance,issubclass,iter,len,%
license,list,locals,long,map,max,min,object,oct,open,ord,pow,property,%
quit,range,raw_input,reduce,reload,repr,reversed,round,set,setattr,%
slice,sorted,staticmethod,str,sum,super,tuple,type,unichr,unicode,%
vars,xrange,zip},
 emphstyle=[4]\color{purple}\bfseries,
 upquote=true,
 morecomment=[s][\color{lightgreen}]{"""}{"""},
 commentstyle=\color{red}\slshape,
 literate={>>>}{\textbf{\textcolor{darkred}{>{>}>}}}3%
          {...}{{\textcolor{gray}{...}}}3,
 procnamekeys={def,class},
 procnamestyle=\color{blue}\textbf,
framexleftmargin=1mm, framextopmargin=1mm, frame=shadowbox,
rulesepcolor=\color{blue},
 breaklines=true,
 #1
}}{}%%%%Here it was missing }
```

And the example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\input{pythonperfect}%input better than include here
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 blah blah blah
\end{figure}

\begin{python}
 for a
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've marked your inline code with backticks `\``. (Sorry for the edit clash; I actually made my changes twice.)

Comment: I keep on doing the code bit wrong don't I :) Also I made about 5 edits because of things I missed. No worries

Comment: Hendrik: Thank you both. I tried to compile the code Hendrik posted, and that didn't run either. It's obviously a problem with my install. I'm going to update the packages (I think I'll do a full TexLive install from scratch, to fix any other problems while I'm at it). Then I'll try again. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron: It's not my code but Martin's code. I just gave Martin's answer some minor polishing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I played with this for quite a few hours, and I guess it's only fair to share my findings with anyone else who might be interested.

Here's what I found: Martin's code works great if you want to use the `python` environment, with `\begin{python}...\end{python}`. He uncommented a line:

```
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]{
```

Then he stuck in a `#1` at the end (to use the option), and added a `}`. But that brace is not the brace the LaTeX is talking about in the error. It's only needed *after* you add the aforementioned line, where you open a brace.

The problem with this is that it only works if you want to use the `python` environment. But if you want to use `listings` to include complete python files, as I do, this does not work. `\lstnewenvironment` overrides `\lstinputlisting`, which is why I had it commented out in the first place.

In any case, you can use it if you want the environment, or you can leave it out. Or figure out a way to use both at the same time.

After installing a new install of TexLive-full, I got the the thing to work--but only in the sterile environment of a trial document. When I put it into the document I'm working on, I ran into the same issues I started with. Evidently, it's some kind of clash  with something else in the document.

Lots of trial and error tells me that it's the use of the `setspace` package that's interfering with... something. I can't for the life of me figure out what. It does work in a simple document. Weird.

In any case, taking out `setspace` means you have to also take out `\setstretch{1}`, but it's not such a big deal.

Thanks to those who answered. I appreciate it. And Martin, good point about `\input` vs. `\include`. I didn't realize that.

Comment: Now I've marked also _your_ inline code with backticks `\``. Looks nicer like this, doesn't it? `:-)`

Comment: Yes, posting you own final solution as answer is good and encouraged.